# how to find in SQL if the a time ( format:yymmdd hours:mins:secs) lies within a time frame?

Tags: sql, sybase

Can someone please help me out with a SQL query that will tell if a particular time lies within a given time frame.

```
start_time = 20140304 11:00:00
end_time   = 20140303 08:00:00
```

If i give `20140303 07:00:00` , it should say if it lies within the mentioned time frame.  For the current scenario , it should pass and print "yes"

**UPDATE**
These values are varchar format

Comment: Take a look at `BETWEEN`: http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00170.1260/html/iqapg/iqapg318.htm

Comment: are you storing these dates as datetime datatype?

Comment: they are in varchar format

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `where` clause:

```
where (start_time < end_time and @VALUE between start_time and end_time) or
      (start_time > end_time and @VALUE between end_time and start_time)
```

I assume you want a match, regardless of whether `start_time` is before or after `end_time`.

EDIT:

If you wanted this in a `select`, then use `case`:

```
select (case when (start_time < end_time and @VALUE between start_time and end_time) or
                  (start_time > end_time and @VALUE between end_time and start_time)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as Flag
```

Comment: what if i wanted to print 1 if it matches and print 0 if it does not ?

Comment: Thanks, will try this query and let you know soon :)